# How can I use Xively MQTT server with Arduino?

Tags: arduino, mqtt, xively

I'm trying to connect my Arduino with ethernet to Xively using their MQTT server but am having trouble authenticating. When I do `client.connect("arduinoMQTT")` I get a failure. I tried passing my API Key as a username by doing `client.connect("arduinoMQTT", "APIKEY")` but then the code won't compile.

How can I authenticate to the Xively MQTT server on arduino.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check the api docs for the Arduino MQTT client, you'll see you need to provide a password argument as well as the username. When connecting to Xively, you use your api key as username and null for the password:

```
client.connect("arduinoMQTT", "APIKEY",null)
```

You should probably use something a bit more unique than arduinoMQTT as the client id as well.

Comment: Oops... Didn't mean to create this as a CW. Oh well